# How can you derive a meter if you were transported in a world with no knowledge of the metric system?

Tags: medieval, technological-development, science-in-society

I'm making a novel where the protagonist is reincarnated into a world in a medieval setting? How would one go about this? Note that the world he is in may not necessarily be the same size as earth.

Comment: Are you trying to create the exact same measurement of a meter or just create a similar system?

Comment: Easy. First develop chemistry, physics and spectroscopy to the point where you can purify cesium, understand what the hyperfine levels of the ground state are, and can measure their periods. Then develop a clock which can measure time with high accuracy (about 1 part per trillion would be a good start). A second is 9,192,631,770 times the difference. Then find a way to measure the speed of light with decent accuracy (1 part per billion is enough.) Then take 1 meter to be equal to the distance travelled by light in a vaccum in 1/299,792,458 seconds.

Comment: Other commenters are assuming you want hyperfine precision from your protagonist's measurements. As if you wanted him or her to design printed circuits in your Medieval setting.  So the answer is going to depend on what your protagonist wants to do with that meter. And go read _[The Flying Sorcerers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flying_Sorcerers)_!

Comment: Most people I know know how tall they are in their prefered unit system with a precision of about 1cm (or whatever). If it's an average dude, he is about 180cm tall. I'm sure you can do the math. Or are you refering to the definition of the metre relative to the Meridian of Earth? Does he want to know how big the planet is? I think if this is the case, this is neither a duplicate nor a bad question, just sloppily asked. People here close too quickly these days, I personally wouldn't be so sure that this is actually a duplicate of the linked question

Comment: The marked duplicate rules out a lot of answers which fit this question. I would go so far as to say the answers to that question are on the fringes of what would be a good answer for this one, because due to the precision constraint they are unlikely to be achievable for an individual. Perhaps this question is too broad because it doesn't define a level of precision - but is not an exact duplicate. If the question were edited to specify that it is looking for answers achievable in the lifetime of the individual, and good enough for everyday use, then the area of overlap would be removed.

Comment: @AlexP: I'm lazy. Can't I just use the [length of a pendulum of 2 second period](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/meter.html)?

Comment: @nzaman the planet does not necessarily have the same gravity as earth.

Comment: @nzaman: The period of the pendulum $T = 2\pi \sqrt{L / g}$ depends both on the length of the pendulum and the gravitational acceleration.

Comment: @AlexP, Harbinger: Hence me being lazy. Unless _g_ is massively different, you should be getting _L_ accurate to 1 decimal point. Good enough for medievals, I should think. (Also less chance of getting burnt at the stake.)

Comment: @nzaman: If all you want is 10% precision then even lazier is to remember that the distance between the tips of you outstretched arms is about equal to your height.

Comment: @AlexP: If you already know your height in metres, why not simply use that as a reference, then?